# websocket connection error in https website

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket, cakephp-2.3

I want to implement basic chat application in php using the websocket and its working fine in my local server and http website but its not working for the https website. I have implemented the chat from this [Simple Chat using php](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket)

In javascript i was connecting to websocket like this

```
var wsUri = "ws://mydomain:9000/server.php";   
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

I have used for my https website `wss://` instead of `ws://`

And its giving the error in console

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain:9000/server.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And if i observe the terminal its giving the error like "`socket_getpeername() : unable to retrieve the peer name[107] Transport endpoint is not connected`"

I googled for the same issue but i didn't get any proper solution. Please suggest me how can i set the socket options for ssl.

Answer (score 0):

In this same case we get an error display like below error.
**"failed: Error in connection establishment:
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"**.

In server page we use socket extensions functions, starts with **soket_**.

If any know about how to connect ssl with this socket extensions functions.Any clarification my question please post your command.